# Delete enemy from vector array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, erase

This is my first question on this site. I learn programming for a year and I always found a answer for my problem in projects. I know that this is REALLY simple problem and here is a code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Wave.h"

Wave::~Wave()
{
}

void Wave::setEnemyCount(int count) {
    nemyCount = count;
}

bool Wave::createWave() {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {
        enemyArray.push_back(Enemy());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyArray.size(); i++) {
        int randomPositionX = rand() % 150 + 10;
        int randomPositionY = rand() % 50 + 10;

        if (!enemyArray.at(i).init(randomPositionX, randomPositionY)) {
            std::cout << "Create wave(init enemies) - failed\n";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void Wave::drawWave(Window* window) {
    window->setCursor({ 0, 2 });
    window->setColor(Window::Color::RED);
    std::cout << "Enemies: " << enemyArray.size();
    window->setColor(Window::Color::WHITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyArray.size(); i++) {
        enemyArray.at(i).draw(window);
        //std::cout << i;
    }
}

void Wave::update(Bullet* bullet, Player* player) {

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyArray.size(); i++) {
        if (player->checkShoot()) {
            if ((bullet->getPositionX() >= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionX() && bullet->getPositionX() <= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionX() + 5)) {
                if ((bullet->getPositionY() >= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionY() && bullet->getPositionY() <= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionY() + 5)) {
                    player->addScore(10);
                    enemyArray.erase(enemyArray.begin() + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (enemyArray.size() <= 0) {
        std::cout << "WAVE COMPLETE";
        Sleep(2000);
        enemyCount += 5;
        createWave();
    }
}

int Wave::getEnemyCount() const {
    return enemyCount;
}
```

The collision work correct, but when bullet touch a enemy of index for example: 5, a code always remove the enemy of last index, so I can remove each enemy only shoot to one enemy with index 5 or 1 or 7.

Comment: A vector can't have a size less than zero. In fact, the size returned by `size` is *unsigned*, so it can't be less than zero. Therefor a comparison using less-than is wrong.

Comment: The code looks correct as long as the bullet never touches two enemies with consecutive index. Please show a [mcve], including example input/output.

Comment: As for your problem, think about the vector indexes when you erase an element. What is the new index of the *next* element in the vector? The element after the one you remove? Try drawing out the vector on a piece of squared paper, where each square is a single element. Then "erase" an element and ***move*** the remaining elements down to fill the hole of the erased element.

Comment: I know but this is not important now. I have a problem in the loop. This is all method and I think that the better way is a paste all code :).

Comment: [mcve] please. All code is not minimal.

Comment: I wanted to show a variable "i" and the "i" is equals a size of my array and when I touch enemy, a method delete the last enemy in array and then "i" is smaller by 1.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually it's <=0, not <0...

Comment: @user202729 Less than or less than or equal is irrelevant, a good compiler with the proper flags would (and IMO *should*) still warn about it.

Comment: Use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`.  A list adjusts to changing sizes a lot better than a vector.  To delete an item in a vector or array, you have to move elements up to overwrite the erased slot and then change the capacity.  With a list, you remove the node.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `enemyArray.erase(...)` you shouldn't increment `i` because you will skip one element.

So you should rewrite the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemyArray.size();) {
    if (player->checkShoot()) {
        if ((bullet->getPositionX() >= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionX() && bullet->getPositionX() <= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionX() + 5)) {
            if ((bullet->getPositionY() >= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionY() && bullet->getPositionY() <= enemyArray.at(i).getPositionY() + 5)) {
                player->addScore(10);
                enemyArray.erase(enemyArray.begin() + i);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Or, with a more idiomatic style:

```
for (auto it = enemyArray.begin(), end = enemyArray.end();it!=end;) {
    if (player->checkShoot()) {
        if ((bullet->getPositionX() >= it->getPositionX() && bullet->getPositionX() <= it->getPositionX() + 5)) {
            if ((bullet->getPositionY() >= it->.getPositionY() && bullet->getPositionY() <= it->getPositionY() + 5)) {
                player->addScore(10);
                enemyArray.erase(it);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    ++it;
}
```

Of course, if you wan a single enemy to be removed at a time, you should `break` instead of `continue` in the loop, after having erased the element.

For completeness, you can also use `std::remove_if` if you want to remove all enemies touched by the bullet, it's more optimal than the 2 loops above, because it does less moving of elements when multiple elements are removed.

Comment: I tried to use this and when bullet touch a one enemy, program remove a few enemys at the same time.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. I cant paste my all code in the editor :(, he dont recognize what is a code and what is a text :D.

Comment: @KewinWoźny I can only encourage you to debug your game, for example print the state of variables to see what's going on, and where is the problem.